# Electron Main process communication with Daemon running with Higher privilege

Tags: electron, cross-platform, ipc, daemon

Im working on a cross platform desktop application using **Electron JS**. The app needs to communicate with a local daemon that is executing with higher privilege.
Problem 1:

1. Establishing connection between the daemon (written in C++) and the Main process (written in Node JS). How will RPC work with cross language client and server? Which client side library(s) can be used to achieve the same?
2. Elevating privileges of the Main process in order to communicate with the higher privileged daemon. How can this be achieved in Mac OS, Linux, Windows?

There are examples of applications like **Atom**, **Slack**, **VS Code** that are built on top of Electron that also uses some IPC under the hood. Any pointers to address both the problems together.